# Symmetric space associated to a connected semisimple linear algebraic $\mathbb{Q}$-group

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

In the introduction of some [article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1146169912), there is the following statement:

> Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a semisimple linear connected algebraic group defined over
>   $\mathbb{Q}$. 
>   Let $G = \mathbf{G}(\mathbb{R})$ be the real locus
>   of G, which is a Lie group with finitely many connected components.
>   Let $K \subset G$ be a maximal compact subgroup of G.
>
> Then $X = G/K$ is
>   a symmetric space of noncompact type

**Why is $X$ a symmetric space and why of the noncompact type?**

In order to make $G/K$ a symmetric space, one needs an involution $\sigma \colon G \to G$ such that $(G^\sigma)^0 \subseteq K \subseteq G^\sigma$. Where does this come from?$^{(1)}$

Also in order to be of the noncompact type, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ needs to be non-compact and if $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{p}$ is the decomposition into the eigenspaces of $\Theta = d_e\sigma$ and $B$ the Killing form of $\mathfrak{g}$, then
$$
B_\Theta(X,Y) := -B(X,\Theta(Y))
$$
has to be positiv definite. I don't see why this is true.

$(1)$ Please note that $Z(G)$ is not assumed to be finite.

Comment: $X$ is a symmetric space only after it's been endowed with a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric

Comment: Also there's no point in fixing a $\mathbf{Q}$-structure. Second, $Z(G)$ is automatically finite when $G$ is algebraic semisimple.

Comment: If $G$ has compact simple factors then they are contained in $K$ and hence are killed in $G/K$. So there no harm in assuming before hand that there are no such compact factors.

Comment: Is there a source where this is written down or does one have to assemble this together oneself? It starts to make sense for me, but a lot of things are still not clear, for example, do I get the involution from the fact that $\mathfrak{g}$ has some Cartan involution which yields a maximal compact subgroup $K'$ and $K$ is conjugate to $K'$?

Comment: Or is there a direct way to get the $G$-invariant Riemannian metric turning $G/K$ into a symmetric space?

Comment: The standard reference for this is Helgason's book "Differential geometry, Lie groups and Symmetric spaces"

Comment: Not sure that "get the Riemannian metric into a symmetric space" means. A Riemannian manifold is or is not a symmetric space. There's a direct way to construct the Riemannian metric: choose a $K$-invariant metric on the base-point of $G/K$ and translate (this works for all $G$ Lie group and $K$ compact subgroup). When $G$ is semisimple and $K$ is maximal compact, this is automatically symmetric, but this requires a proof.

Comment: On has the Killing form on the Lie algebra of $G$, I think the orthogonal of the Lie algebra of $K$ is automatically definite-positive. Then one needs an involution of $G$ preserving $K$ and the Killing form and acting as minus identity on the orthogonal of $K$; I think this is how it works. This should be in Helgason's book.